# Saving an edited Core Data entity is not being saved

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, tableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a TableView with multiple sections that is populated with entities (called 'Item') using the Core Data framework. In the cellForRowAt delegate method I call a callback that is called when the user hits the 'Enter' key. This callback should save the text they just typed in the cell's textfield to the core data model and then add a new empty cell right below it.

All of this works except for when the section is empty and you try to set item.name equal to textfield.text. If I add multiple items to that section then it will save all the cells I just created and added to the data model except for the very first one.

At first I was updating the item and then saving the context but I would get an error along the lines of "error: Mutating a managed object after it has been removed from its context". See code below.

```
    /// Customize the contents of the cell
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: homeCellId, for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
    let item = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    cell.nameText.text = item.name

    /// Called when user hits Enter on the keyboard
    /// This allows them to enter a new item
    cell.addNewCell = { [weak self] newTitle in
        guard let `self` = self else {return} // Capture self

        if cell.nameText.text != "" {

            let newTitle: String = cell.nameText.text! // Grab the name øf the item the user just entered
            let itemToUpdate = self.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] // Grab the item they typed

            itemToUpdate.name = cell.nameText.text
            self.saveContext()


            // Create reference to indexpath below the existing cell
            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row+1, section: indexPath.section) // Set the indexPath to the cell below
            // Create new dummy item
            let newPlaceholderItem = self.coreDataManager.addItem(toCategory: self.categories[indexPath.section], withItemName: "")
            // Add dummy item to tableview array
            self.items[indexPath.section].append(newPlaceholderItem)
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic) // Insert it into the tableView
        } else {
            print("Can not add new cell since current cell is empty")
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

After doing a lot of Googling I found the solution to the above error was to use performBackgroundTask() illustrated below.

```
/// Customize the contents of the cell
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: homeCellId, for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
    let item = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    cell.nameText.text = item.name

    /// Called when user hits Enter on the keyboard
    /// This allows them to enter a new item
    cell.addNewCell = { [weak self] newTitle in
        guard let `self` = self else {return} // Capture self


        if cell.nameText.text != "" {

            let newTitle: String = cell.nameText.text! // Grab the name øf the item the user just entered
            let itemToUpdate = self.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] // Grab the item they typed

            let container = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer // Grab the persistent container

            container.performBackgroundTask { (context) in
                // Make sure the object isn't null
                guard let queueSafeItem = context.object(with: itemToUpdate.objectID) as? Item else {
                    print("Error, could not update item.")
                    return
                }

                queueSafeItem.name = newTitle // Update the title of the item

                // Save the change that the user made to the cell he just edited
                do {
                    print("Saving context after modifying item")
                    try context.save()
                } catch {
                    print("Error saving when creating new cell: \(error)")
                }
            }

            // Create reference to indexpath below the existing cell
            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row+1, section: indexPath.section) // Set the indexPath to the cell below
            // Create new dummy item
            let newPlaceholderItem = self.coreDataManager.addItem(toCategory: self.categories[indexPath.section], withItemName: "")
            // Add dummy item to tableview array
            self.items[indexPath.section].append(newPlaceholderItem)
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic) // Insert it into the tableView
        } else {
            print("Can not add new cell since current cell is empty")
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging, it seems that I wasn't properly saving the "dummy" cells and had to reformat some code. No error on Xcode or Swift's end - just the usual programmer error.